# Apktool doesn't recompile, even the app unmodified

Tags: android, linux, apktool

I can't use Apktool to recompile, even I don't modified anything. I run:

```
apktool b <dir app>
```

I can't imagine why of this behavior. I tried some nuances: run with sudo, to use `./dir-app`, ever it launchs a lot of warnings in console that I guess doesn't worth to comment it of the face. Any ideas?

As I said, I tried sudo, ./dirapp, I try not modify the app, I can't recompile, even if I didn't modify the app. However, I realized a pattern: a lot of lines like that

```
W: res/drawable/$widget_streak_frozen_background_extra__12.xml: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
```

This says me there mustn't be that dollar sign in name of the files, there are a lot of files with dollar sign in their names. IDK if it helps say that app is a foreign languages, above it says "must contain only [a-z0-9_.] characters." But my opinion is that there shouldn't be that dollar sign there. The files like the above are between single quotes in system, like:

```
'$widget_background_extra_nyp_pre_8pm__30.xml'
```

But it there's a misbehavior.

Comment: App protection system use such tricks and intentionally use invalid names in a way that Android still can execute the app but reversing tools run into problems. What do you want to modify on the app, something in small code or something in xml, text if image resources?

Comment: I want to cheat the app for to have infinity life. It's difficult to me saying what I want change just I don't have a mean to test the changing for while.

Comment: Usually this should not require modification to resources. Therefore you can bypass the naming problem by disabling resource decompilation via `--no-res` switch. However an APK file that uses special resource names to prevent de-/recompiling contains with a high probability a lot of other measures like signature check, may be even play integrity check.